# Gradient flows in metric spaces

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, metric-spaces, gradient-flows

What is a good introduction in gradient flows in metric spaces? I know the book Gradient flows: in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures by Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Gigli and Giuseppe Savaré, but is too hard for an introduction.

Can someone make this a community wiki? I cannot find how you have to do that...

Comment: See this answer http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/941/community-wiki-checkbox-disappeared/942#942

Comment: @Américo Tavares: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Since I don't get any answers here, would this be an okay question for MO (community wiki)?

Comment: @Jonas: I think you should try.

Comment: I got a reply there, this can be closed. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43083/textbooks-or-notes-on-gradient-flows-in-metric-spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this question I will post the answer which I got at Mathoverflow.

I have read [Philippe Clément's notes on gradient flows in metric spaces](http://www.cgti.nl/gf/lec-notes-philippe.pdf).

Another nice book which I have found is the book "Optimal Transport, old and new" by Cédric Villani". Nice book. It is in the Yellow Sale in Europe until the end of July.

Answer (score 2):

Also there are [notes](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf) by Onno van Gaans, partly based on Clément's notes.

Comment: I know those, I did the course he gave before the course lectures started by studying Clément's notes.